# Issue with AWS cognito sample app

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to run this AWS cognito sample app from https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/CognitoSync-Sample/Swift. I can add new data set but as soon as i try to sync/refresh i get this below error. I am not trying with any provider. Just simple sync of data.

And Here is the steps i did -

1.Downloaded the sample app from github.

2.Installed AWSCognito using pod as given

3.And Created a identity pool in Amazon cognito console

4.and updated the constants in Constants.swift -

static let COGNITO_REGIONTYPE = AWSRegionType.USEast1
static let COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL_ID = "us-east-1_XXXXXXXXX"

Here is the error from my console -

```
2016-05-11 15:43:49.643 CognitoSyncDemo[18352:6625488] AWSiOSSDKv2 [Debug] AWSCognitoSQLiteManager.m line:179 | __51-[AWSCognitoSQLiteManager initializeDatasetTables:]_block_invoke | sqlString = 'INSERT INTO CognitoMetadata(Dataset,ModifiedBy,IdentityId) VALUES (?,?,?)'
2016-05-11 15:43:49.643 CognitoSyncDemo[18352:6625488] AWSiOSSDKv2 [Debug] AWSCognitoSQLiteManager.m line:282 | __53-[AWSCognitoSQLiteManager loadDatasetMetadata:error:]_block_invoke | query = 'SELECT LastSyncCount, LastModified, ModifiedBy, CreationDate, DataStorage, RecordCount FROM CognitoMetadata WHERE IdentityId = ? and Dataset = ?'
2016-05-11 15:43:49.647 CognitoSyncDemo[18352:6625968] AWSiOSSDKv2 [Verbose] AWSURLRequestSerialization.m line:103 | -[AWSJSONRequestSerializer serializeRequest:headers:parameters:] | Request body: [{"IdentityPoolId":"us-east-1_1kBTIfzWu"}]
2016-05-11 15:43:50.942 CognitoSyncDemo[18352:6626097] AWSiOSSDKv2 [Debug] AWSURLResponseSerialization.m line:74 | -[AWSJSONResponseSerializer responseObjectForResponse:originalRequest:currentRequest:data:error:] | Response header: [{
Connection = close;
"Content-Length" = 218;
"Content-Type" = "application/x-amz-json-1.1";
Date = "Wed, 11 May 2016 10:13:50 GMT";
"x-amzn-ErrorMessage" = "1 validation error detected: Value 'us-east-1_1kBTIfzWu' at 'identityPoolId' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\w-]+:[0-9a-f-]+";
"x-amzn-ErrorType" = "ValidationException:";
"x-amzn-RequestId" = "0ec70838-1761-11e6-91c2-e77b976ab658";
}]
2016-05-11 15:43:50.942 CognitoSyncDemo[18352:6626097] AWSiOSSDKv2 [Verbose] AWSURLResponseSerialization.m line:79 | -[AWSJSONResponseSerializer responseObjectForResponse:originalRequest:currentRequest:data:error:] | Response body: [{"__type":"ValidationException","message":"1 validation error detected: Value 'us-east-1_1kBTIfzWu' at 'identityPoolId' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\w-]+:[0-9a-f-]+"}]
2016-05-11 15:43:50.943 CognitoSyncDemo[18352:6626097] AWSiOSSDKv2 [Error] AWSIdentityProvider.m line:185 | __51-[AWSAbstractCognitoIdentityProvider getIdentityId]_block_invoke169 | GetId failed. Error is [Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)" UserInfo={__type=ValidationException, message=1 validation error detected: Value 'us-east-1_1kBTIfzWu' at 'identityPoolId' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\w-]+:[0-9a-f-]+}]
2016-05-11 15:43:50.943 CognitoSyncDemo[18352:6625968] AWSiOSSDKv2 [Verbose] AWSURLRequestSerialization.m line:103 | -[AWSJSONRequestSerializer serializeRequest:headers:parameters:] | Request body: [{"IdentityPoolId":"us-east-1_1kBTIfzWu"}]
2016-05-11 15:43:52.168 CognitoSyncDemo[18352:6626097] AWSiOSSDKv2 [Debug] AWSURLResponseSerialization.m line:74 | -[AWSJSONResponseSerializer responseObjectForResponse:originalRequest:currentRequest:data:error:] | Response header: [{
Connection = close;
"Content-Length" = 218;
"Content-Type" = "application/x-amz-json-1.1";
Date = "Wed, 11 May 2016 10:13:51 GMT";
"x-amzn-ErrorMessage" = "1 validation error detected: Value 'us-east-1_1kBTIfzWu' at 'identityPoolId' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\w-]+:[0-9a-f-]+";
"x-amzn-ErrorType" = "ValidationException:";
"x-amzn-RequestId" = "0f7792fc-1761-11e6-9ad4-59d8bf47e69e";
}]
2016-05-11 15:43:52.168 CognitoSyncDemo[18352:6626097] AWSiOSSDKv2 [Verbose] AWSURLResponseSerialization.m line:79 | -[AWSJSONResponseSerializer responseObjectForResponse:originalRequest:currentRequest:data:error:] | Response body: [{"__type":"ValidationException","message":"1 validation error detected: Value 'us-east-1_1kBTIfzWu' at 'identityPoolId' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\w-]+:[0-9a-f-]+"}]
2016-05-11 15:43:52.168 CognitoSyncDemo[18352:6626097] AWSiOSSDKv2 [Error] AWSIdentityProvider.m line:185 | __51-[AWSAbstractCognitoIdentityProvider getIdentityId]_block_invoke169 | GetId failed. Error is [Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)" UserInfo={__type=ValidationException, message=1 validation error detected: Value 'us-east-1_1kBTIfzWu' at 'identityPoolId' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\w-]+:[0-9a-f-]+}]
2016-05-11 15:43:52.169 CognitoSyncDemo[18352:6626097] AWSiOSSDKv2 [Error] AWSCognitoService.m line:176 | __36-[AWSCognito refreshDatasetMetadata]_block_invoke147 | Unable to list datasets: Error Domain=com.amazon.cognito.AWSCognitoErrorDomain Code=-4000 "(null)"
```

What am i missing? I am very new to AWS services, any guidance would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Richa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was using user pool id instead of identity pool id. Its resolved now.

Comment: Just had the same problem. Just for the record the "pool id" in AWS user pools is incredibly misleading. What AWS wants you to do in the sample app is to go to the *Federated Identities*, start new identity pool and get the "identity pool id". fml

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is almost always using a user pool id instead of a identity pool.

Note that if you enter the correct identity pool id when initializing AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider() it will work in simulator, even with a wrong id in your info.plist AWS dictionary descriptor. But on device it's going to use the info.plist pool id, and fail if it's wrong. That bit me, so make sure your pool id is correct in both locations.